# How can a variable be assigned to two objects?

Tags: python-3.x

```
g = None
try:
   g = open("mydata.txt", "r")
except IOError:
   print(’Python could not open the file mydata.txt.’)
if g:
   try:
      lines = g.readlines()
      print("The list of lines is:")
      print(lines)
   except IOError:
      print(’Error while trying to read the data in the file.’)
```

This is an example of using `try` and `except` in python from my textbook. The textbook stated that "`g` is given an initial binding of `None` (which is treated as `False` within the boolean context of the `if` statement)". From my understanding, `g` already holds a file object returned from the `open` function, how can it be treated as `False` within the boolean context of the `if` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be both `None` and the contents of the file at the same time; the idea is that if `open()` fails, and the first `Except` block is hit, then `g will still be equal to`None`.

So if the `open()` process completes successfully, than the `if g` statement will evaluate to true, and the function will proceed. If the `open()` process fails, `g` will still be equal to `None`, and therefore the `if g` statement will evaluate to false and the `readlines()` section will be skipped.

Answer (score 1):

`g` changes from holding a `None` to a File object when it's reassigned at:

```
g = open("mydata.txt", "r")
```

It doesn't "have 2 objects" at once.

Comment: Thanks for the response.But how did `g` reassigned back `None` in the if statement? The textbook said that `g` is treated as False within the boolean context of the if statement.

Comment: @alexlau It's never reassigned back. The purpose of the `try`/`catch` is to catch the exception that `open` can throw if it can't open the file. If `open` throws an exception, the reassignment doesn't happen, so `g` will still hold `None` when the `try` exits. `if g:` is basically checking if the open succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

so it is important to understand that Python is an **interpreted language** which is **executed statement by statement**

when this code is compiled the compiler know that `g` is `None` from `g = None`. but the compiler keeps reading more lines. When it reads `g = open("mydata.txt", "r")` then the variable `g` now reassign to holds a file object and no longer `none`